# Async.js - Deferring execution while still accessing the correct array index

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to us [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) to process an array of items.  Is there some cute way to get this to work properly?  If you're smarter than I, you'd except that because of the deferred execution, http://3 gets printed three times.

**[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gYZhw/1/)**

```
var a_servers = ['http://1', 'http://2', 'http://3'];

var a_actions = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a_servers.length; i += 1)
{
    var server = a_servers[i];

    a_actions.push(function(callback)
    {
        document.write(server  + '<br/>');
        callback(false, server );
    });
}

async.series(a_actions, function(err, a_servers)
{
    document.write('processed ' + a_servers.length + ' servers<br>');
    console.info(a_servers);
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a classic closure scope issue. You need to pass the `server` variable from the outer scope to the inner scope to get the desired behavior. You can use an IIFE for this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a_servers.length; i += 1)
{
    var server = a_servers[i];

    a_actions.push((function(server) {
        return function(callback) {
            document.write(server  + '<br/>');
            callback(false, server );

    })(server));
}
```

Comment: Gah, thanks, just figured it out and came back to ask if there was an easier way.  http://jsfiddle.net/gYZhw/2/

Comment: My general pattern is to define a top level function that defines and returns the closure, with the closure taking ("closing over") the interesting parameters as part of the closure scope of the top-level function. Then it clearly separates your closure scope complexity from what the loop is trying to accomplish/build. So you end up with `a_actions.push(makeWriter(server));`, which is clearer I think.